# Setting expression on report builder using IIf and First aggregate is not working

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, aggregate

I have three datasets in my report, I'm trying to just set an expression in a textbox for one of the datasets - I am trying to do:

if IsCompleted = 1, show dateSurveyed, otherwise show "N/A" (for testing I've been just trying to use "works" rather than a date)

I have tried:
=IIf(First(Fields!IsCompleted.Value, "CompletedSurvey") = "1", "works", "N/A")
(this one runs, but shows N/A when it should show "works"

=first(IIf((Fields!IsCompleted.Value) = "1", "works", "n/a"), "CompletedSurvey")

I've also tried removing "first", but then I get an error saying that I must have it contain in aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope.

I feel like I've tried a bunch more other options but nothing has worked.

Any suggestions?

My datasets:
[Dataset CompletedSurvey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL9YC.png)

Comment: to start, just set the expression to `=FIRST(Fields!cCompleted.Value)` and see what you get returned, it may not be what you expect. If you need more help, it will help if you edit your question and show a sample of your dataset data and also and filters or sorting that could impact the result

Comment: @AlanSchofield hm, thanks for the tip. I had to write it this way: =First(Fields!IsCompleted.Value, "CompletedSurvey") as it won't work without specifying dataset, but yeah it shows nothing (it should show 1). I will look into this a bit, thank you

Comment: @AlanSchofield Actually one more question - my query on the dataset does not include this field IsCompleted, but I added it in manually (I right clicked the existing dataset CompletedSurvey and added in a query field). Is it because it's not included in my query that it is showing up as an empty value?

Comment: It should work OK even if the field is a computed field in your dataset. Assuming the dataset contains more than 1 record, how can you be certain which record is first, or will they always be the same in every record? That's why I mentioned checking the sorting for your dataset. Also try MAX() and MIN() instead of First() and check you get the expected results. If this does not help, show a sample of data from your dataset and let me know the scope of the textbox (in a table/matrix - if so show the report design; or in a textbox outside of any table/matrix) etc.

Comment: @AlanSchofield you actually made me realize I just needed to make a separate dataset, this dataset uses info from the same table I want but it returns different information (this dataset returns a set of questions and responses for a certain completedsurveyId. What I need would come from a single row with that same id.) Sorry if that doesn't make sense but regardless you helped me troubleshoot so thanks!

Comment: no problem, glad you got there in the end.